# Unable to figure out how to get this RockScissorPaper game in Java to tell me if the user or the computer won

Tags: java

So I have my code compiled here. I'm not spotting what I'm doing wrong, but basically I want the programme to take in the user's choice of Rock, Paper or Scissors; I want the programme to randomly choose and I want the programme to display who the winner is.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissor {
private User user;
private Computer computer;
private int userScore;
private int computerScore;
private int numberOfGames;

private enum Move {
ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS;


public int compareMoves(Move otherMove) {
    // A tie
    if (this == otherMove)
        return 0;

    switch (this) {
    case ROCK:
        return (otherMove == SCISSORS ? 1 : -1);
    case PAPER:
        return (otherMove == ROCK ? 1 : -1);
    case SCISSORS:
        return (otherMove == PAPER ? 1 : -1);
    }       

    return 0;
}
}

private class User {
private Scanner inputScanner;


public User(){
inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public Move getMove(){
System.out.println("Make you choice: Rock, paper or scissors");

String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
char firstletter = userInput.charAt(0);
char firstLetter = 0;
if (firstLetter == 'R' || firstLetter == 'P' || firstLetter == 'S') {
    switch (firstLetter) {
    case 'R':
        return Move.ROCK;
    case 'P':
        return Move.PAPER;
    case 'S':
        return Move.SCISSORS;
    }
}
return getMove();
}

public boolean playAgain(){
    System.out.print("Do you want to play again?");
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
    return userInput.charAt(0) == 'Y';
}
}
private class Computer {
public Move getMove() {
    Move[] moves = Move.values();
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(moves.length);
    return moves[index];
}
}

public  RockPaperScissor() {
user = new User();
computer = new Computer();
userScore = 0;
computerScore = 0;
numberOfGames = 0;
}
public void startGame() {
System.out.println("ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS!");

// Get moves
Move userMove = user.getMove();
Move computerMove = computer.getMove();
System.out.println("\nYou played " + userMove + ".");
System.out.println("Computer played " + computerMove + ".\n");

// Compare moves and determine winner
int compareMoves = userMove.compareMoves(computerMove);
switch (compareMoves) {
case 0: // Tie
    System.out.println("Tie!");
    break;
case 1: // User wins
    System.out.println(userMove + " beats " + computerMove + ". You won!");
    userScore++;
    break;
case -1: // Computer wins
    System.out.println(computerMove + " beats " + userMove + ". You lost.");
    computerScore++;
    break;
}
numberOfGames++;

// Ask the user to play again
if (user.playAgain()) {
    System.out.println();
    startGame();
} else {
    printGameStats();}
}
    private void printGameStats() {
        int wins = userScore;
        int losses = computerScore;
        int ties <= numberOfGames - userScore = computerScore;
        double percentageWon = (wins + ((double) ties) / 2) / numberOfGames;

        System.out.print("+");
        printDashes(68);
        System.out.println("+");

        System.out.printf("| %6s | %6s | %6s | %12s | %14s | \n",
                "WINS", "LOSSES", "TIES", "GAMES PLAYED", "PERCENTAGE WON");

        System.out.print("|");
        printDashes(10);
        System.out.println("+");
        printDashes(10);
        System.out.print("+");
        printDashes(10);
        System.out.print("+");
        printDashes(16);
        System.out.print("+");
        printDashes(18);
        System.out.println("|");

        System.out.printf("| %6d | %6d | %6d | %%12d | %13.2f%% |\n",
                    wins, losses, ties, numberOfGames, percentageWon * 100);
        System.out.print("+");
        printDashes(68);
        System.out.println("+");
}


private void printDashes(int numberOfDashes) {
for (int i =0; i < numberOfDashes; i++) {
    System.out.print("-");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
RockPaperScissor game = new RockPaperScissor();
game.startGame();
}
}
```

Comment: And what problem are you having exactly? Other than you can make the `Computer.getMove()` more compact as `return Move.values()[new Random().nextInt(Move.values().length)];`?

Comment: Well, when I run the programme it just keeps asking me what I choose and doesn't show what the computer decided nor who won.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the described failure is found in the `User.getMove()` method. There is a quasi-duplicate definition of `firstLetter`. The current code uses the variable `firstLetter` which is set to 0, and ignores the user input, gathered in `char firstletter`. Change the variable.

```
 public Move getMove()
    {
        System.out.println("Make you choice: Rock, paper or scissors");

        String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        char firstLetter = userInput.charAt(0);  //<-- Fix the camelCase
        // char firstLetter = 0;                  //<-- Remove this line
        if (firstLetter == 'R' || firstLetter == 'P'
                || firstLetter == 'S') {
            switch (firstLetter) {
            case 'R':
                return Move.ROCK;
            case 'P':
                return Move.PAPER;
            case 'S':
                return Move.SCISSORS;
            }
        }
        return getMove();
    }
```

**Additional info:**
There is a format definition mistake in the `printGameStats` where a line has a doubled %. Line needs to be like this to run:

```
System.out.printf("| %6d | %6d | %6d | %12d | %13.2f%% |\n", wins,
            losses, ties, numberOfGames, percentageWon * 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted that for me :)